# Adding New User programmatically in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I've built a new SharePoint 2010 Web Site. My authantication type is Claims Based Auth. As you know, we use groups,members to manage or add users/permissions in Site Settings. I want to know that if I can make it with programmaticly. I mean I want to add new page for ex Register.aspx and Login.aspx. I've done Login.aspx with a code:

```
bool status = SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(Context.Request.UrlReferrer,
    TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text);

if (!status)
{
    Label1.Text = "Wrong Userid or Password";
}
else
{
    if (Context.Request.QueryString.Keys.Count > 1)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Context.Request.QueryString["Source"].ToString());
    } 
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect(Context.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"].ToString());
    }
}
```

In this page, user have 2 x TextBoxes and a button. He/She can enter username and password and then login. At this point, I need a page to make new registration. I googled it a bit, but cant find enough information. My question is How can I make .aspx page which can be use for new membership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bad:  `Response.Redirect(Context.Request.QueryString["Source"].ToString()`. What if the user enters [www.mysite.com/mysite?Source=**http://www.myrealbadvirus.com**](http://www.mysite.com/mysite?Source=**http://www.myrealbadvirus.com**)?
Don't redirect directly to a query string.

Here some links to get you started:

- [Programmatically granting permissions to claims](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805111141/https://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-granting-permissions-claims/)
- [SharePoint : Add group of users to the user collection programmatically](https://web.archive.org/web/20140520051526/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karthick/archive/2006/03/16/553026.aspx)
- [Create Forms Based Authentication (FBA) programmatically users in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.solidq.com/sharepoint/Post.aspx?ID=47&title=Create%20Forms%20Based%20Authentication%20%28FBA%29%20programmatically%20users%20in%20SharePoint%202010)
- [Programmatically create user groups Sharepoint 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20180201060855/http://www.learningsharepoint.com:80/2010/09/03/programmatically-create-user-groups-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: It is a sample code. The point is SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(Context.Request.UrlReferrer,
    TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text); this. Not a Response.Redirect. Your second link is close to my question. But why there isnt a password? I mean the user need username and password.

Comment: I understand your question a bit better now. How about this link: "Add New User To SharePoint Site By Using ASP.Net 2.0 Membership Provider" http://beyinmoss2007.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/add-new-user-to-sharepoint-site-by-using-aspnet-20-membership-provider/

Comment: Yes. Thats nice. Thank you. I've found a sample project too. Check out if you want http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/7450

Answer (score 0):

To access the user profile service you need to have permissions set up in advance. You have to add the user as Administrator with full permissions (Administrators menu) as well as give the user Full access to connection permission (Permission menu).